# Adding two values to $.POST in PHP

Tags: php, api, post

I'm working with an API and would like to post 2 values as 1, but I can't quite figure out the syntax, or the right words to search to figure this out;

```
"ContactNameFirst" => $_POST['ContactNameFirst'],
"ContactNameLast" => $_POST['ContactNameLast'],
// 
"ContactNameFull" => $_POST['ContactNameFirst ContactNameLast'],
```

Thanks

Comment: I have a form that I'm sending data from, to a data array, into a curl connection to a CRM. I'd Like to only ask for First/Last Name on the form and Post those to the CRM as the full name field. I'm not a php developer, some of the terms escape me. 
Working on testing the answer provided now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `concatenate` the two variables as follows:

```
$_POST['ContactNameFirst'] . ' ' . $_POST['ContactNameLast']
```